# can anyone help to understand heroku ssl

Tags: heroku

Not getting why I need to add Heroku SSL addon and then purchase SSL certificate and add to my Heroku app, does it mandatory to purchase Heroku SSL to add my SSL certificate into Heroku and why

Answer (score 1):

You only have to pay the certificate price if you are using a paid dyno.  You are correct that you have to pay for the certificate AND SSL addon if you are using the free dyno.

https://blog.heroku.com/ssl-is-now-included-on-all-paid-dynos